# how to change the gif picture size in android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, animated-gif

Now I know how to draw a GIF picture in android, here is the code:

```
public class GIFView extends View{        
private Movie movie;  
private InputStream is;  
private long moviestart;  
public GIFView(Context context) {  
    super(context);
    is=getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.anim_cerca);  
    movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);
}  

@Override  
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();  

    if (moviestart == 0) 
        moviestart = now;  

    int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
    movie.setTime(relTime);
    movie.draw(canvas,10,10);
    this.invalidate();
}
```

}

At the end, there is the `movie.draw(canvas,x,y)` code, where the x and y is the coordinate for the gif picture (x=left, y=top).  But how could I change the width and the height of the movie? Maybe give the right and bottom coordinates, but how, where?  Thank you!

Comment: I guess you have tried canvas.scale()?

Comment: yes, I tried it, but nothing has changed. I mean nothing in the size, but the picture gone, when I added this method.

Answer (score 19):

i had the same problem here is my solution,
add this code in ondraw method before movie.draw

```
 canvas.scale((float)this.getWidth() / (float)movie.width(),(float)this.getHeight() /      (float)movie.height());
```

or

```
canvas.scale(1.9f, 1.21f);//this changes according to screen size
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
  implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.4'
```

library
then add this to the xml

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```